# Getting ComboBox.ListIndex with few copies of elements

Tags: excel, vba

I had a ComboBox List with two the same values with the `ListFillRange` value: `Sheet2!A2:A4`:

[image]

List in Sheet2:

[image]

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()

Dim ComboBoxList As String

'Counts how many values in column A, which is '4'
ComboBoxList = Application.Evaluate("COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A)")

'Changes ListFillRange Value into 'Sheet2!A2:A4'
ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "Sheet2!A2:A" + ComboBoxList

Debug.Print ComboBox1.ListIndex
```

And wanted to print out the 3rd index which is the value should be '2':

```
Debug.Print ComboBox.ListIndex
```

But returns '1' instead of '2'

Edit: The list is made out of listfillrange. Not by AddItem

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. If I create a user form with a ComboBox and add the same item 3 times `Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "Test"` and then select the 3ʳᵈ item, then `Debug.Print Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex` shows `2` correctly (numbering starts with `0`). • Please give a [mcve] of your issue that contains everything to reproduce the issue.

Comment: mine uses the listfillrange to make a list in combobox. Should i use AddItem so it will work instead of listfillrange? edit: I forgot that the combobox list is made out of listfillrange. I should add that

Comment: So are you speaking about an ActiveX control on a worksheet then? Please clarify and give more information and a **full example** ([mcve]). Even using `ListFillRange` I cannot reproduce your issue. Works perfectly here.

Comment: I edited the post so u can see what the code does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have the `Debug.Print ComboBox1.ListIndex` in the `ComboBox1_DropButtonClick`. Remove it there and put it into the `ComboBox1_Change` event and at works properly.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
    Dim ComboBoxList As String
    
    'Counts how many values in column A
    ComboBoxList = Application.Evaluate("COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A)")
    
    'Changes ListFillRange Value into 'Sheet2!A2:A4'
    ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "Sheet2!A2:A" + ComboBoxList
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Debug.Print Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it helps! PS: Im sorry that I forgot adding more details to it.

Comment: I recommend to stay away from ActiveX and use FormControls instead. ActiveX is known to cause many strange issues.